# JVMJ9TI001E Agent library "C:\Program could not be opened (The specified module could not be found. )

Tags: websphere-8, dynatrace

JVMJ9TI001E Agent library "C:\Program could not be opened (The specified module could not be found. )
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9jvmti26(-3): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed.

Why i am getting this error after setting the dynatrace javaagent path.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the classic problem with windows paths having whitespace in them.  Try setting the the javaagent path to the short filename C:\progra~1... (or whatever) instead of C:\Program Files...

Answer (score 0):

there is an server.xml file in your server installation path for server configuration. in this file include genericJvmArguments arg. delete in content write only genericJvmArguments="" it will be ok